# Laravel 4.2,save and access files inside storage folder

Tags: laravel, video, laravel-4, html5-video, storage

I'm working on a laravel 4.2 project,and i'm supposed to upload videos,save them inside the storage folder,and then display them inside a page where the user can play these videos.The first part of saving the videos is done,but the problem is getting the files.

i looked everywhere,and unlike laravel 5.x,it seem like there's no clear way to access the storage folder and get files (even the Storage::get cannot be used).

as an easy example for testing,i'm starting by linking a simple image from inside the storage folder,still doesnt work.i tried the url function (blade)

```
<img src="{{url('code/app/storage/files/videos/gg.jpg') }}"/>
```

it gives this line when compiled by the browser:

`<img src="http://dr.test/userptl/code/app/storage/files/videos/gg.jpg"/`>

the path code/app/storage/files/videos/gg.jpg is correct,but still unable to access to the image.

storage_path() cannot be used because it generates the full path from the root,which is,incorrect.

is there any way to fix this ?

Comment: php artisan storage:link
This will create a symlink from public/storage to storage/app/public for you . Now any file in /storage/app/public can be accessed via a link like:

http://somedomain.com/storage/gg.jpg

Answer (score 0):

When you upload a file, it gets stored in a temp folder.  You have to move it to a publicly accessible folder like.

`$file = $request->file('file');
\Storage::put($path.'/'.$newFilename, file_get_contents($file));`

You may need to have a symbolic link between storage and public to make those files accessible.

Answer (score 0):

In case if you are not using

```
php artisan storage:link
```

add following code to your router:

```
Route::get('storage/{filename}', function ($filename)
{
    $path = storage_path('public/' . $filename);

    if (!File::exists($path)) {
        abort(404);
    }

    $file = File::get($path);
    $type = File::mimeType($path);

    $result = Response::make($file, 200);
    $result->header("Content-Type", $type);

    return $result;
});
```

Then in view you can use like:

```
<img src="{{ asset("storage/gg.jpg")}}"/>
```